# ¿Cómo cerrar navbar de bootstrap 5 al dar clic fuera de él en Angular 13?

Tags: angular, bootstrap

Quiero poder **cerrar el navbar al dar clic fuera de él**, estoy usando bootstrap 5, es decir **no usa jQuery**, en **Angular 13**,

A continuación les muestro el html del componente navbar
No estoy seguro de como hacer que al dar clic fuera del componente de vuelva a su posición original

```html
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #2d2d2d;">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="">PG</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">


      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a 
            class="nav-link" 
            aria-current="page" 
            routerLink=""
            routerLinkActive="active"  
            [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"
          >
            Inicio
          </a>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Este es el app.component que es donde lo tengo

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar><router-outlet></router-outlet>
```